# How do I write CSS for multiple divs that fill out the browser window?

Tags: css, safari

What I want is to have mutliple divs after one another, that each is the full width and height of the browser/viewport. When the browser is rezized, the divs should rezise accordingly.

I have succesfully managed to do this in FF and IE (just width: auto and 100% height on each div), but Safari & Chrome still doesn't get it. The weird thing is, i don't get what happening in those browsers. While the first div behaves as the way i want, the height gets bigger and bigger for each div, and absolut positioned elements whithin each div ends upp somewhere on the bottom of the page; it's a mess.

an example of what i am trying to do can be found here: http://konstfuck.se/test/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You don't have a valid Doctype, so your page will be rendered in Quirks mode and, as Henri Sivonen [wrote](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/),

> [i]n the Quirks mode the browsers
>   violate contemporary Web format
>   specifications in order to avoid
>   “breaking” pages authored according to
>   practices that were prevalent in the
>   late 1990s. Different browsers
>   implement different quirks. In
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8, the
>   Quirks mode is effectively frozen IE
>   5.5. In other browsers, the Quirks mode is a handful of deviations from
>   the Almost Standards mode.

2) Add `height: 100%` to `html` and `body`. As the spec [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height):

> The percentage is calculated with
>   respect to the height of the generated
>   box's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block). If the height
>   of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly (i.e., it depends
>   on content height), and this element
>   is not absolutely positioned, the
>   value computes to 'auto'.

So, if you don't specify the `height` of the containing block, as is the case in your example, the `height` is set to `auto`.

Comment: Thank you very much! At first I added the doctype (rookie mistake to have left it out in the first place...) but then it became even wierder and broke i FF too. Then i added 100% height to html and body, and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Odd behaviour... I suspect the problem is that the BODY element grows as the divs are sized, so as each one has it's 100% height assigned it grows - and the height of the next big is greater.

Try wrapping them all in a div, give that a 100% height and see if it corrects the problem.

```
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: May be you are right with that. So div1 would be 100% height, div2 would be 200% height and div3 would be 300% height. But in fact this is the correct interpretation, because the body is growing.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div>div 1</div>
<div>div 2</div>
<div>div 3</div>
<div>div 4</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a4k3g/1/).

Note: Tested in FF and Chrome only.

Comment: I understand you merely want to demonstrate that the height of the box is correct, but adding a border to a box which height is already 100% will result in a box with an overall height that's larger than the viewport, because you didn't select the border-box [box model](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html).

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution that worked, in combination whith adding a correct doctype, as Marcel pointed out.